How can I add a template suggestion for a field formatter based on the current view mode?
In my Drupal 10 theme how I can get Entity View Mode? I use this to rewrite suggestions
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_image_formatter_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $entity = $variables['item']->getEntity();
  $field_name = $variables['item']->getParent()->getName();
  $suggestions[] = 'image_formatter__' . $entity->getEntityTypeId() . '__' . $entity->bundle() . '__' . $field_name;
}

But I need also View Mode (full, teaser). Something like this:
image-formatter--node--article--VIEW-MODE--field-image.html.twig

Does this answer your question? how to get view_mode from within hook_field_formatter_view

While the duplicate question was asked more than 10 years ago the answer still applies: Field formatters are view mode agnostic. Add a second field formatter if you need a different behavior in a different view mode.

It doesn't work that way. A field formatter is view mode-agnostic. If you need different logic on another view mode, add a second field formatter.
What you can do, though, is trying to get other distinct information from the $variables and add a suggestion based on that. The image_formatter for example also comes with an info about the current image_style.
So, you can create a new image style with the same dimensions as the currently used one. Now in the other view mode choose this new image style.
Now you can add a suggestion based on the current image style:
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_image_formatter_alter(array &$suggestions, array &$variables) {
  $suggestions[] = 'image_formatter__' . $variables['image_style'];
}

